# Using table leaves a blank page and also runs off of the page when making CV

Tags: tables, cv

I'm trying to make my CV and am encountering a couple of problems. More specifically:

1. When I try to add my name, the table that I'm using for the body of my CV either goes to the next page (leaving my name on the first page), or if I adjust the position of the name to go inside the table then the table itself goes to the next page, leaving the first page blank.
2. The contents of the CV (i.e., the table) "run off" the page, disappearing.

Screenshots and the (minimal) code are as follows:

### Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l l}

\noindent  \LARGE{\textbf{John Doe}} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\\\toprule
\normalsize \\

\Large{Contact} & \\
\Large{Information} & \\

\\
     
\Large{Research} & \\
\Large{Interests} & \\

\\

\Large{Education}
     & \textbf{John University} \\
     & M.S. & 2019 - present \\
     & \indent GPA:
     \\ \\
     & B.A. & 2012 - 2019 \\
     & B.S. \\
     & \indent GPA:
     & \\
     
\\
     
\Large{Projects}   & \textbf{Department, University} \\
     & Instructor, Fundamentals of the Global Economy, 2016 \\
     & \\
     &\textbf{Department, University} \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2014-2015 \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2012-2014 \\
     & \\
     & \textbf{Department, University} \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2013 \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2013 \\
     & \\
 \Large{Publications}    & \textbf{International} \\
     & Postdoctoral Research Associate \\
     & Project: Title of Research \\
     & \textbf{Domestic (Korean)} \\
     & \\
     
\Large{Teaching} & \textbf{Teaching Assistant} \\
\Large{Experience} & \indent \\
                   & \indent \\
 
\\ \\
 
\Large{Academic} & \textbf{Peer Reviewing}\\
\Large{Services} & \indent \\ 
                 & \indent \\ 
                 & \indent \\ 
                 & \indent \\ 


  
\Large{Languages} & \\
\Large{and Skills} & \\

\\

\Large{Test} & \textbf{TOEFL iBT: } \\ 
\Large{Scores} & \indent \\ 
             & \indent \\ 
             & \indent \\ 
             & \indent \\ 
             \\
             & \textbf{GRE: } & August 18th, 2018 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Regarding the table running off, I thought of making separate tables for each page, but that seemed a bit bothersome and I was wondering if there were a way for LaTeX to configure this automatically. I'm not sure how to address the first issue (blank page) though and was hoping someone would be able to point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: please add the complete code as a MWE

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. It's done.

Comment: It seems, that your table is to large to fit on one page. Try to use `longtable` instead of`tabular` table environment.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the name + table (in the first case) or the whole table (after putting your name in the table) can fit on the page! If it is a close call, then maybe leave out some lines or maybe adjust `\arraystretch` so that it will fit. If the table is much longer than the page, then use a longtable (package longtable) instead, as it can break into parts at page boundaries.

Don't use a table environment if you don't want the table to "float" to another page. Use bare "tabular" (or, more precisely, \noindent\begin{tabular}...) or "longtable".

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
    \begin{longtable}{@{} >{\Large}l l l}
\textbf{John Doe}   &   &   \\
    \toprule
Contact         &   &       \\
Information     &   &       \\
                &   &       \\

Research        &   &       \\
Interests       &   &       \\
                &   &       \\
Education       & \textbf{John University}      &   \\
                & M.S.                          & 2019 - present    \\
                & \indent GPA:                  &   \\
                &   &   \\
                & B.A.                          & 2012 - 2019       \\
                & B.S.                          &                   \\
                & \indent GPA:
                &   &   \\
Projects        & \textbf{Department, University}   &   \\
                & Instructor, 
                Fundamentals of the Global Economy, 2016    &   \\
                &   &   \\
                &\textbf{Department, University}    &   \\
                & Job Title, Course Name, 2014-2015 &   \\
                & Job Title, Course Name, 2012-2014 &   \\
                &   &   \\
                & \textbf{Department, University}   &   \\
                & Job Title, Course Name, 2013  &   \\
                & Job Title, Course Name, 2013  &   \\
                &   &   \\
Publications    & \textbf{International}        &   \\
                & Postdoctoral Research Associate   &   \\
                & Project: Title of Research    &   \\
                & \textbf{Domestic (Korean)}    &   \\
                &   &   \\
Teaching        & \textbf{Teaching Assistant}   &   \\
Experience      & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\

Academic        & \textbf{Peer Reviewing}       &   \\
Services        & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\
Languages       &           &   \\
and Skills      &           &   \\
Test            & \textbf{TOEFL iBT:}           &   \\
Scores          & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\
                & \indent   &   \\
                & \textbf{GRE:}                 & August 18th, 2018 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It occupy (with showed contents) two pages, i.e. length of table is (of course) depends on its contents... Image below show the first page:

[image]

You my consider to use `twoside` document type. In above MWE see (consistent) employment of ampersand: each table row should have two of them.

Answer (score 1):

With `xltabular` you can make sure your table is automatically split into several pages if the length exceeds one page. (If you compile your document, you get a warning: "Overfull \vbox (100.58302pt too high) has occurred ..."). With the help of `xltabular` and its `X` type column you can also ensure your table will not flow into the right margin if your entries get longer. If you want to, you can easily repeat the name on all pages of the CV. If you don't want thi,s, just remove `\endhead` from the below example code. If you want to prevent a pagebreak between certain rows (e.g. between "Language"  and "and SKills") you can use `\\*` instead of `\\`  wherever you want to prevent a pagebreak.

In order to avoid the repetition of `\Large` in all cells of the first column,  I have used `>{\Large}l`. This automatically applies `\Large` to all cells in the corresponding column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\Large}l X l@{}}

\LARGE \textbf{John Doe} \\
\midrule
\endhead
 \\
 Contact & \\
  Information & \\

\\
     
 Research & \\
 Interests & \\

\\

Education
     & \textbf{John University} \\
     & M.S. & 2019 - present \\
     & \indent GPA:
     \\ \\
     & B.A. & 2012 - 2019 \\
     & B.S. \\
     & \indent GPA:
     & \\
     
\\
     
Projects   & \textbf{Department, University} \\
     & Instructor, Fundamentals of the Global Economy, 2016 \\
     & \\
     &\textbf{Department, University} \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2014-2015 \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2012-2014 \\
     & \\
     & \textbf{Department, University} \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2013 \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2013 \\
     & \\
Publications    & \textbf{International} \\
     & Postdoctoral Research Associate \\
     & Project: Title of Research \\
     & \textbf{Domestic (Korean)} \\
     & \\
     
Teaching & \textbf{Teaching Assistant} \\
Experience & \indent \\
                   & \indent \\
 
\\ \\
 
Academic & \textbf{Peer Reviewing}\\
Services & \indent \\ 
                 & \indent \\ 
                 & \indent \\ 
                 & \indent \\ 


  
Languages & \\
and Skills & \\

\\

Test & \textbf{TOEFL iBT: } \\ 
Scores & \indent \\ 
             & \indent \\ 
             & \indent \\ 
             & \indent \\ 
             \\
             & \textbf{GRE: } & August 18th, 2018 \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use `\\` to create blank lines instead use `\\[2pt]` -- your table is quite large better to reduce fontsize if you prefer

**With normal font**

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l}
\LARGE{\textbf{Seankala}}&&& \\[2pt]
\toprule[2pt]
\Large{Contact} & &&\\
\Large{Information} &&& \\
\Large{Research} & &&\\
\Large{Interests} & &&\\
\Large{Education}
     & \textbf{John University}&& \\
     & M.S. & 2019 - present &\\
     & \indent GPA:     &&\\
     & B.A. & 2012 - 2019 &\\
     & B.S. &&\\
     & \indent GPA:&&\\
     & \\
\Large{Projects}   & \textbf{Department, University}&& \\
     & Instructor, Fundamentals of the Global Economy, 2016 &&\\
     & &&\\
     &\textbf{Department, University}&& \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2014-2015 &&\\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2012-2014 &&\\
     & &&\\
     & \textbf{Department, University}&& \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2013&& \\
     & Job Title, Course Name, 2013 &&\\
     & &&\\
 \Large{Publications}    & \textbf{International} &&\\
     & Postdoctoral Research Associate &&\\
     & Project: Title of Research &&\\
     & \textbf{Domestic (Korean)} &&\\
     &&& \\
\Large{Teaching} & \textbf{Teaching Assistant} &&\\
\Large{Experience} & \indent&& \\
                   & \indent &&\\
\Large{Academic} & \textbf{Peer Reviewing}&&\\
\Large{Services} & \indent &&\\ 
                 & \indent &&\\ 
                 & \indent &&\\ 
                 & \indent &&\\ 
\Large{Languages} & &&\\
\Large{and Skills} & &&\\
\Large{Test} & \textbf{TOEFL iBT: } &&\\ 
\Large{Scores} & \indent &&\\ 
             & \indent &&\\ 
             & \indent &&\\ 
             & \indent &&\\ 
             & \textbf{GRE: } & August 18th, 2018& \\
             \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**With footnotesize font**

[image]

Can be achieved by adding `\footnotesize` in the starting of the table--

```
\noindent\footnotesize \begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l}
```

Comment: `\vspace` inside of a tabular does not really do anything useful. While it is indeed true that `\\ ` inside of a text is a bad idea, it just adds an empty table row when used inside of a tabular. An alternative to using `\\ \\ ` inside of a tabular could be using `\\[10pt]` (or any other length or your choice).